# Docker container discovery by hostnames doesn't work

Tags: docker, docker-swarm, docker-network, docker-stack

I use the following docker compose file located at `/tmp/compose.yml` for docker stack deployment :

```
version: "3.6"

services:
  service-A:
    image: service-A
    networks:
      - net
    hostname: "service-A-{{.Task.Slot}}"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2

  service-B:
    image: service-B
    networks:
      - net
    hostname: "service-B-{{.Task.Slot}}"
    deploy:
      replicas: 2

networks:

  net:
```

Run commands:

```
docker network create -d overlay net
docker stack deploy -c /tmp/compose.yml my
```

My expectation was that `service-A` individual containers will be able to discover `service-B` containers by container pre defined hostnames: `service-B-1, service-B-2`.
However, `ping service-B-1` from within any `service-A` container fails.

[Docs](https://docs.docker.com/v17.09/engine/userguide/networking/default_network/configure-dns/) state:

> **hostname** Sets the hostname by which the container knows itself. This is written
>   into /etc/hostname, into /etc/hosts as the name of the container's
>   host-facing IP address, and is the name that /bin/bash inside the
>   container will display inside its prompt. But the hostname is not easy
>   to see from outside the container. It will not appear in docker ps nor
>   in the /etc/hosts file of any other container.

How to achieve docker swarm service container to service container communication by container pre defined hostnames?

The only way that works is adding entries like:

```
[service_B_container_1_virtual_ip] service-B-1
[service_B_container_2_virtual_ip] service-B-2
```

to `/etc/hosts` of `service-A` containers.

It's interesting also that if `hostname` is not set in `docker-composes` file, but generated by docker, `ping [container_id]` succeeds even across multi host docker swarm.

I expected the same behavior for pre defined hostnames.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is any straightforward way to do this. And the more I think about it, the more it makes sense that *there should not be* a way to do what you are asking, *by design*.

One of the fundamental properties of a stack service is that it should be deployable in such a way that Docker is able to treat all of the replicas in that service interchangeably. If you need to connect to individual instances, it suggests that those containers should not be created as service replicas in the first place, as there is *something* that distinguishes them. A proper stack service should be able to treat every replica as an ephemeral entity that can be destroyed and rebuilt at any time, and the operation should be invisible from the outside.

What you **can** do from inside the Docker network is reference the service entity using the service name. So in your example, `ping Service-A` should work from any container in the stack, and so will `ping Service-B`.

The names of individual containers in a service are things like

```
my_stack_redis.1.y1pwzeg8239yb6n6ynefs78br
my_stack_webserver.1.d6cxx8nlg7db9m2poy9wfjdyd
```

If you absolutely must gain access to those names from within a container, the only way I can think of is to expose `/var/run/docker.sock` inside the container via bind mount when starting. Then, `chmod 750` on the socket as part of the `CMD / ENTRYPOINT` script so a non-root user can read it. Now you should be able to install the Docker CLI and use `docker network inspect` to discover the names of actual service members, and `jq` to parse them out (you'll probably need to add both packages to the image). But at that point, the better option would probably be to separate those non-fungible containers into their own service groups.