# Docker container host name cannot be resolved inside docker network

Tags: docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm, hostname

In my swarm docker-compose file I am creating 7 replicas of apache storm supervisor as shown here.

```
storm_supervisor:
  image: storm:2.0.0
  deploy:
    replicas: 7
  command: storm supervisor
  networks:
    - my_network
  hostname: "stormsupervisor{{.Task.Slot}}"
```

However the hostname that I am setting is not being resolved anywhere within the swarm network. i.e. when I exec into the zookeeper container running on the same swarm network, I cannot ping "stormsupervisor1, "stormsupervisor2, etc. Instead I can only ping them by their respective container id. I can also ping using the service name (storm_supervisor), but that only returns one of the containers

Answer (score 0):

The host keyword is used to set the hostname of the container in `/etc/hosts` and `/etc/hostname`, it is not used at all with the swarm service discovery. check this [link for more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59055358/docker-container-discovery-by-hostnames-doesnt-work)